# XmlApplicationContext : Is there a way of knowing all configuration problems at once?

Tags: spring.net

XmlApplicationContext returns an exception on the first XML definition that does not match a class definition. Is there a way to get a list of all problems in my XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't such an option afaik. If the containers encounters an error, then it has got a broken dependency and has got no idea how this would effect the remainder of the configuration. Safest thing is to fail right then and there.

It is very common to encounter problems when crafting xml configuration for Spring.NET. You mistype a class name, property name or constructor type and find out when you run (or integration-test) your application. You fix it, run it again, only to find out you made a similar error on the next line. This can get frustrating, so I fully understand where your question comes from.

There are a few things you can do to minimize making errors in your xml configuration:

- Install the [Spring xsd files](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/vsnet.html#vsnet-config-section) in Visual Studio - this will validate your xml while you type it.
- Install the [Spring.NET Visual Studio Addin](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/vsnet.html#d4e10026), requires VS 2010. This will give you:

  - Intellisense-like type completion, property name completion and constructor argument name completion.
  - Some xml snippets to quickly insert object definitions and more.
  - SDK quick info tooltips
  - See [this video](http://maruxelo.free.fr/spring/index2.html) for a demo
- If you don't run VS 2010, you can also checkout some of the [features of Resharper](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/vsnet.html#d4e10093) that are useful for Spring.NET

I recommend doing both. I think installing the add in also installs the xsd files.

You can also consider switching (parts of) you configuration to [Spring.NET's CodeConfig](http://www.springframework.net/codeconfig/index.html), but that's beyond the scope of this question.